# Django: Update a single field in existing model with forms.py

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, django, django-forms

I need to allow the user to edit a field to customise the name of the field with a stylish modal window. I've been trying to go over tutorials for AJAX but it's going a bit over my head.

My HTML:

```
<div id="editCustomParam" class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <form class="form-horizontal" id="chamber-form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h3>Edit Parameter Name</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    {{ custom_param_form|crispy }}
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary submit_property" id="property_submit">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

The button and element to edit:

```
<td><i id="edit_{{parameter.id}}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editCustomParam" class="far fa-edit" title="Edit Parameter Name"></i>&emsp;<span>{{parameter.parameter_name_userdef}}</span></td>
```

The AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.submit_parameter').click(function(el) {
        var parameter_name = $("#id_parameter_name_userdef").val();
        var sensor_id = {{sensor.id}}
        $.post("{% url 'sensor' sensor.id %}", {
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{csrf_token}}'
        }, function(data) {
            location.reload();
        }).done();
    });
});
```

The form:

```
class CustomParameterForm(ModelForm):
    parameter_name_userdef = forms.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        model = SensorParameter
        fields = ['parameter_name_userdef']
```

The view:

```
class SensorInfoView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Sensor
    template_name = 'expert/sensor.html'

    def get(self, request, sensor_id):
        sensor = Sensor.objects.get(pk=sensor_id)
        chamber = Chamber.objects.get(sensor=sensor)
        sensor_parameters = SensorParameter.objects.filter(sensor=sensor)
        custom_param_form = CustomParameterForm()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'sensor': sensor,
                                                    'chamber': chamber,
                                                    'custom_param_form': custom_param_form,
                                                    'sensor_parameters': sensor_parameters})

    def post(self, request, sensor_id):
        instance = get_object_or_404(Sensor, id=id)
        form = CustomParameterForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('next_view')
        return render(request, 'expert/sensor.html', {'custom_param_form': custom_param_form})
```

The model:

```
class SensorParameter(models.Model):
    sensor                  = models.ForeignKey(Sensor)
    parameter               = models.ForeignKey(Parameter)
    parameter_name_userdef  = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, default=parameter)
    live_value              = models.FloatField()
```

Now, the procedure seems straightforward, it's the execution that I'm not quite catching on.

- Retrieve the relevant model instances with a GET (Done).
- Make an edit button that brings up the modal with the form in it (Done).
- Make a modal that shows the form from forms.py (Done).
- Write a bit of AJAX that will send relevant data to the view (Not done!)
- Handle the POST request in the view (Not done!)

I've been reading a few tutorials, but I try to follow the steps and I'm still now sure how to deal with the AJAX bit. I'm still new at Django, and this will also be my first try with AJAX, so I'm not sure if I made any glaring newbie mistakes.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Can't you better check if it's updated in the model?

```
class SensorParameter(models.Model):
    sensor = models.ForeignKey(Sensor)
    parameter = models.ForeignKey(Parameter)
    parameter_name_userdef = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, default=parameter)
    live_value = models.FloatField()

    __sensor = None
    __parameter = None
    __parameter_name_userdef = None
    __live_value = None

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SensorParameter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__sensor = self.parameter_name_userdef
        self.__parameter = self.parameter
        self.__parameter_name_userdef = self.parameter_name_userdef
        self.__live_value = self.live_value

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.sensor == self.__sensor and (
                self.parameter_name_userdef != self.__parameter_name_userdef):
            super(SensorParameter, self).save(force_insert, force_update, *args, **kwargs)
            self.__parameter_name_userdef = self.parameter_name_userdef
        else:
            super(SensorParameter, self).save(force_insert, force_update, *args, **kwargs)
            self.__sensor = self.parameter_name_userdef
            self.__parameter = self.parameter
            self.__parameter_name_userdef = self.parameter_name_userdef
            self.__live_value = self.live_value
```

Basically what I made here is when a form creates a new `SensorParameter`, then it will submit every value, but when there's already a `SensorParameter` with that `ForeignKey`, then it will only update the value `parameter_name_userdef`.

Though you'd have to send the `ForeignKey` from the `sensor` as well, because you want to check which `SensorParameter` needs to be updated I assume? But this is how you easily update just 1 single value in the models, if you want you can set it for multiple values as well.